# How can I limit the input languages?

Tags: keyboard, languages

How can I limit the number of input languages on the keyboard? I would only like to see the 3 I use. I have a HTC desire S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a HTC Desire, but I'm assuming the menus/behaviour should be similar:

> Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Touch Input -> International keyboard

Select the languages you want to use. That should restrict the keyboard list to the ones you have specified.